# Rails: Pie Charts legend in Chartkicks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, highcharts, chartkick

In `highcharts` to show the percentage along with `pie_charts`, a legend can be customized like this:

```
legend: {labelFormat: '{name} : {y} ({percentage}%)'}
```

But in `chartkicks` I can't find how to do like this?

Comment: `chartkick` is just a ruby gem with which you can use `highcharts` or `google charts` as backend library. Not sure what you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: Yes @aliibrahim . So in the configuration how you set highcharts properties when working with chartkicks

Comment: Can I use both at time?

Comment: From which this issue fix

Comment: @NishithKantChaturvedi see my answer and relevant link to the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the documentation specified on the [ChartKick Gem](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick) homepage, it says:

```
You can pass options directly to the charting library with:

<%= line_chart data, library: {backgroundColor: "#eee"} %>
```

So in your scenario, you should try something like:

```
<%= pie_chart data, library: {legend: {labelFormat: '{name} : {y} ({percentage}%)'}} %>
```

Comment: Just to be sure, which version of highcharts are you using and including in your project using `javascript_include_tag` and by any chance you are not including google charts api as well via javascript?